# URL Length restriction on GetFileByServerRelativeUrl

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest

I'm trying to get file by using GetFileByServerRelativeUrl and getting the url length restriction error. In some posts I see that people recommend to use this call with parameter , like this :

```
https://tenant-my.sharepoint.com/personal/user_account_tenant_onmicrosoft_com/_api/web/getfilebyserverrelativeurl(@v)/$value?@v='....'
```

But when I'm doing this I'm getting next error :

> 400 : {"error":{"code":"-1,
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"The
>   query string \"serverRelativeUrl\" is missing or invalid."}}}

What I'm doing wrong ? I'm doing HTTP GET from Java code.